# Amazon SageMaker Downloading Files from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm storing midi files in an S3 bucket and am trying to download them into the SageMake jupyter notebook.  I am using this code

```
import os
import boto3  # Python library for Amazon API 
import botocore
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
def download_from_s3(url):
    """ex: url = s3://sagemakerbucketname/data/validation.tfrecords"""
    url_parts = url.split("/")  # => ['s3:', '', 'sagemakerbucketname', 'data', ...
    bucket_name = url_parts[2]
    key = os.path.join(*url_parts[3:])
    filename = url_parts[-1]
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        try:
            # Create an S3 client
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
            print('Downloading {} to {}'.format(url, filename))
            s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(key, filename)
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
                print('The object {} does not exist in bucket {}'.format(
                    key, bucket_name))
            else:
                raise
```

however I am getting An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Here are the permissions attached for the S3:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The S3 bucket `sagemakerbucketname` you are using should be in the same region as the Sagemaker Notebook Instance. 
The IAM role associated with the notebook instance should be given permission to access the S3 bucket.

Run below command in the sagemaker notebook to get the IAM role

`role = get_execution_role()`

Verify the role used to launch the notebook has permissions to access the S3 bucket. These are the permissions you are expected to have

`{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sagemakerbucketname"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sagemakerbucketname/*"
            ]
        }`

Comment: It has full S3 permission, and is in the same region

Comment: I have updated the permissions expected by sagemaker to access S3 bucket.

Comment: I'm confused as I have tried changing regions multiple times and permissions.  My role has full S3 permissions with all of the ones listed above plus more.  Is there any other reasons I could be getting this error.

Comment: Is your sagemaker instance and bucket in the same region?

Comment: I believe so, the arn of the sagemaker is arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:267752861345:notebook-instance/musicresearch and the S3 shows us East(Ohio) as its region.  Does it matter if I'm using my computer from another country if these are located in the East US